# RDBMS table schema using key-value pairs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a site that will use .NET with a SQL Server database. In creating a database schema, I'm thinking that key-value pairs would be a good approach.

Here is what I have:

`CarAtttribute`:

| Id | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Make |
| 2 | Model |
| 3 | Color |

`CarAtttributeValue`:

| Id | AttributeId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Chevy |
| 2 | 1 | Ford |
| 3 | 1 | Honda |
| 4 | 2 | Blazer |
| 5 | 2 | Camaro |
| 6 | 2 | Cruze |
| 7 | 2 | Fiesta |
| 8 | 2 | F-150 |
| 9 | 2 | Accord |
| 10 | 2 | Civic |
| 11 | 3 | Red |
| 12 | 3 | Black |
| 13 | 3 | White |

`Cars`:

| Id | Make | Model | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 | 11 |

Then for querying I can pass the `AttributeValue` to the stored procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cars
WHERE Make IN (1)
  AND Model IN (5)
  AND Color IN (12,13)
```

I'm wondering if I'm on the right path?

Comment: <oy> You seem to have a mangled half of an [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). It forces every row in `Cars` to have _one_ value (or `null`) for _each_ attribute. Adding a new attribute, e.g. `ChargingKW`, requires altering the table schema. Having multiple values for an attribute, e.g. a red and white vehicle, can't be represented. Going to a pure EAV model has it's own benefits and drawbacks. </oy> You may want to do some research into EAV.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this kind of modeling because you basically limit yourself to 1 value per key, or you have to get into a really gross mess.

Using your model, how would you indicate Japanese car makers vs American car makers? How would you indicate the Pantone color of the color Red? You would instead need to now have a ColorAttribute table and a MakerAttribute table, or heirarchically store them within a single attribute table.

Instead, make a Model table (ID, Model, Make_id), a Color table (ID, color), and a Make table (ID, make), foreign key them to your Cars table, and add joins to your query.

This will allow you to have a good ERD for your model and it will allow you to more cleanly add additional fields to each of your attributes.